# XSLT: Check if a value exists in a list

Tags: xslt, xpath, xslt-1.0

So, I have a variable containing a nodeset with several Size nodes

```
<xsl:variable name="sizes" select="$filter/Size" />
```

I then, need to do a sum on another nodeset, where the Size/@ID exists in this $sizes variable

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(Sizes/Size[ **where @ID in $sizes/@ID** ]/@Value)"/>
```

But I'm struggling on how I write this XPath...in xslt 1.0

Comment: I know the answer is simple, my brain however, is still in long weekend mode.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
<xsl:value-of select="sum(Sizes/Size[@ID = $sizes/@ID]/@Value)"/>
```

if I understand your spec correctly.

This works because of "existential quantification": `A = B` means "some member of node set A is equal to some member of node set B". (In your case, A has at most only one member anyway.)

Comment: ****face palm****, that seemed too easy to even try, lol thanks